# How to find actual row number of an index in a Multi-Index pandas Dataframe where indices are not unique

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

p is a pandas dataframe that looks in Spyder console like below:

```
In [1]: p
Out[1]: 
                                     ncloc        files
ncloc     Correlation Coefficient     1.000000     0.500000
NaN       Sig. (2-tailed)                  NaN     0.000000
          N                        1600.000000  1600.000000
new_lines Correlation Coefficient     0.021537     0.021873
NaN       Sig. (2-tailed)             0.242349     0.238163
          N                        1600.000000  1600.000000
classes   Correlation Coefficient     0.978614     0.993551
NaN       Sig. (2-tailed)             0.000000     0.000000
          N                        1600.000000  1600.000000
```

In Spyder data explorer, p looks like below:
[image]

I can access the element corresponding to 'files' column and 'new_lines' row as:

```
In [2]: p['files']['new_lines']
Out[2]: 
Correlation Coefficient    0.5
Name: files, dtype: float64
```

But the output is of type 'pandas.core.series.Series'.

I can also access the numeric value (of type: numpy.float64) as:

```
In [3]: p['files'][3]
Out[3]: 0.5
```

**Now, how do i find out that the actual row number of the index 'new_lines' in p is 3?**

I can write a for loop to find it out but there should be a very simple way to find out the row number for the index 'new_lines'.

The for loop way to find this is like below:

```
row = 'new_lines'
for r_index in len(p.index):
    if (p.index[r_index][0] == row):
        break
# r_index has the result
```

So, I have my result i.e. row number in the r_index variable. How to do this operation more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html).

## Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ncloc': [1, 0], 'files': [0.5, 2]},
    index=['lines', 'new_lines'])

print(df.index.get_loc('new_lines'))

>>> 1
```